# Custom QDialog causes segfault upon exec()

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault, qdialog, custom-widgets

I have a program that essentially consists of a central `QMainWindow` and a member `QToolbar` pointer.

One action on this toolbar has its `triggered` signal connected to a `ShowNodeEditBox()` slot, which instantiates and attempts to exec a custom `QDialog`-derived widget:

```
 void
 Toolbar::ShowNodeEditBox(){
   ...
   //Side note: The custom box stores a pointer to a custom QGLWidget on the main window
   NodeEditBox nodeEdit(this, m_mainWindow->GetGLScene());
   nodeEdit.exec(); 
 }
```

For some reason, calling exec causes a segfault, even though just constructing the window without it works just fine. The stack trace is as follows:

```
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x00000030922e64ff in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libQtGui.so.4
#2  0x00000030922e795a in QPainter::QPainter(QPaintDevice*) () from /usr/lib64/libQtGui.so.4
#3  0x00000030921fd7af in QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget(QPaintDevice*, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) ()
   from /usr/lib64/libQtGui.so.4
#4  0x00000030923a0675 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libQtGui.so.4
#5  0x00000030923a09c9 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libQtGui.so.4
#6  0x00000030922162da in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libQtGui.so.4
#7  0x00000030922213e7 in QApplication::x11ProcessEvent(_XEvent*) () from /usr/lib64/libQtGui.so.4
#8  0x0000003092249da2 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libQtGui.so.4
#9  0x00007ffff7410f0e in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#10 0x00007ffff7414938 in ?? () from /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#11 0x00007ffff7414a3a in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#12 0x0000003091b7d5f3 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib64/libQtCore.so.4
#13 0x0000003092249a6e in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libQtGui.so.4
#14 0x0000003091b56722 in QEventLoop::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib64/libQtCore.so.4
#15 0x0000003091b569ec in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib64/libQtCore.so.4
#16 0x000000309262aaae in QDialog::exec() () from /usr/lib64/libQtGui.so.4
#17 0x000000000045d9e8 in RoadmapOptions::ShowNodeEditBox (this=0xce5da0) at GUI/RoadmapOptions.cpp:562
#18 0x0000000000486f32 in RoadmapOptions::qt_metacall (this=0xce5da0, _c=QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod, _id=12, _a=0x7fffffffc740)
    at GUI/MOC/moc_RoadmapOptions.cpp:114
```

Something is definitely up here, since I see an 0x0, but I haven't been able to figure it out. The construction of the `NodeEditBox` itself is quite intricate (lots of sliders, labels, etc. all over the place), so I tried clearing it all off and just calling exec on an empty custom box, constructed like this:

```
NodeEditBox::NodeEditBox(QWidget* _parent, GLWidget* _scene){ /* nothing! */ }
```

Lo and behold (and perhaps thankfully, since it's a really complicated widget), this causes the exact same segfault! I also tried making a pointer to a `NodeEditBox` with `new` rather than just instantiating it, as well as making the `NodeEditBox` a pointer member of the toolbar class and constructing it earlier (thus, only doing `exec` in `ShowNodeEditBox()`. And the parent and GLWidget scene pointers are already created, accounted for, and robust, as far as I know. But I still get the same problem every time.

What am I missing here?

**Other info/edit: Using a regular, empty `QDialog` and popping it up instead of the custom version works just fine. So maybe it's a parent-related thing.

Even more interestingly, deriving `NodeEditBox` from `QWidget` instead of `QDialog` works just fine and does not crash! I wanted to use `QDialog`, though, so that I could call `exec.` `show` doesn't seem to work unless the `NodeEditBox` is a member of the toolbar class, which I didn't want because I need multiple, 'disposable' node edit boxes to pop up at different times...

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code and check whether `m_mainWindow->GetGLScene()` is returning a valid pointer?

Comment: It is. But even if it wasn't (general C++ question), would it matter with the empty constructor attempt since I don't use it for anything anyway in that case?

Comment: does a `show()` work?

Comment: `show()` just does nothing. It doesn't segfault, though!

Comment: Related/perhaps silly question: Is the stack trace suggesting that there is supposed to be a `QPaintDevice*` somewhere, but it's null? I never even touch paint-related stuff in my code.. :/

Comment: `nodeEdit.show();` alone does not work here, because `nodeEdit` is destroyed when the function returns (before an event loop gets run that can actually show it). This is what `QDialog::exec()` does - it calls "show" and then starts an event loop, and only returns after the Dialog was closed.

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
NodeEditBox::NodeEditBox(QWidget* _parent, GLWidget* _scene)
: QDialog(parent)
{ /* nothing! */ }
```

instead of

```
NodeEditBox::NodeEditBox(QWidget* _parent, GLWidget* _scene){ /* nothing! */ }
```

- you need to pass through input arguments, otehrwise default ctor is called for unbderlying widget, with 0 parent. Not 100% sure if this causes segfault, but it is definitely error prone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is enough information here to solve this, so here is what I would do to narrow it down:

1. Make sure you can reproduce this crash from a squeaky clean build (ie `make clean`, etc). Sometimes "mysterious" crashes can be caused by an unclean build (outdated objects/moc files, etc).
2. Start with a trivial version of NodeEditBox and work towards the crash. You already stubbed out the constructor - do the same with all other methods and members. Comment them all out, and then put them back in piece by piece to find the minimal version that makes it crash. Maybe post that minimal version, if it still does not make sense to you.
3. Don't get side-tracked with alternative implementations - the code you presented looks ok - you should be able to get it to work. The cause of the crash must be in the code you didn't show here.